# python os module popen and tmpfile functions

Tags: python-2.7

I have two things to ask here.. Please help me with this as i am new to python.

**first**
 i am unable to figure out the usage of pythons os.popen function...what i know is that it is used to open subprocesses...i tried doing the same..tried to open command prompt on windows 7. the documentation gives the syntax as popen(command, [mode, [bufsize]]) and says "open a pipe to or from command. The return value is an open file object connected to the pipe..."  I did not understand what opening a pipe to a command means or what a pipe means.

also if you could kindly explain what is the purpose of popen2 , popen3 and popen4....

**second**

i tries this with os.tmpfile function

```
>>> tmpf=os.tmpfile()
>>> type(tmpf)
<type 'file'>
>>> dir(tmpf)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'close', 'closed', 'encoding', 'errors', 'fileno', 'flush', 'isatty', 'mode', 'name', 'newlines', 'next', 'read', 'readinto', 'readline', 'readlines', 'seek', 'softspace', 'tell', 'truncate', 'write', 'writelines', 'xreadlines']
```

as it says tmpf has a type file

i tried the following

> > > help(file.softspace)

--and--

> > > help(tmpf.softspace)

but to my surprise the output of both help commands was a whole lot different....

may you please explain as to why this behaviour..

eagerly waiting for your help..

thankx in advance  :)

Comment: Have you considered reading the python documentation?!

Comment: I DID READ THE DOCUMENTATION UT IT WAS NOT CLEAR TO ME. KINDLY PARDON AS I AM STILL NAIVE TO PYTHON. WOULD BE HELPFUL IF YOU COULD HELP.

Comment: At least I won't help anyone shouting (caps). Hopefully others do so, too...

Comment: while typing caps felt more clear to read what i was typing(facing some screen problem, hardware issues). it was the only reason to use caps. i did not mean any disrespect or shout. please do not feel offended. you are taking it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

`help(tmpf.softspace)` displays the help of the *value* of `tmpf.softspace` - which is `int`.

`help(file.softspace)` however displays the help for the `softspace` *attribute* - i.e. what it's used for.